# Getting "symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" while integrating unity build into an existing xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I have a project in unity. After making the build for iOS platform, When I try to integrate with the existing Xcode project, I am getting the following error. Any ideas what the problem can be? I am using XCode 10.1. I used Unity 2018.3.1 for the building the project.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/vikasroy/Desktop/codes/sc_ios_app/Development/CaptainCreek/Carthage/Build/iOS'
>   ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from
>   /Users/vikasroy/Desktop/codes/sc_ios_app/unity/MyAvatarIOS9/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o) Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_SetUnityiOS81orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS82orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS100orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS101orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetCrashedCheckBelowForHintsWhyBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetAppLoadAddressBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetAppLoadCommandAddressBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityInitJoysticksBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityUpdateAccelerometerDataBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityIsGyroEnabledBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityUpdateJoystickDataBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetJoystickNameBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetIsCompensatingSensorsBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityMaxQueuedAccelerationEventsBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetMainWindowBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetSetCompensatingSensorsBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityRequestQuitBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityInitMainScreenRenderingCallbackBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityIsGyroAvailableBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetMetalBundleBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityCoreMotionStartBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityUpdateGyroDataBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetMetalDrawableCommandQueueBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetDataContextEAGLBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityBackbufferColorBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDestroyDisplayLinkBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityBackbufferDepthBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetDisplayManagerEndFrameRenderingBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetAcquireDrawableMTLBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS91orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityMakeCurrentContextEAGLBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS110orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityStartActivityIndicatorBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityStopActivityIndicatorBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_CreateBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_ShowBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_HideBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_GetRectBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_SetTextBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_GetTextBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_IsInputHiddenBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_SetCharacterLimitBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetMetalCommandQueueBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_CanGetSelectionBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_CanSetSelectionBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceSetDesiredAccuracyBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityOnDemandResourcesSetLoadingPriorityBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityNotifyHideHomeButtonChangeBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetNiceKeynameBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_IsActiveBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityRequestStoreReviewBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityInitCameraCaptureBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitStartBroadcastingBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityStartCameraCaptureBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS111orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetGLViewControllerBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitHideCameraPreviewBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetAVCapturePermissionBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceGetDistanceFilterBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityRequestAVCapturePermissionBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityVendorIdentifierBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityStopCameraCaptureBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityFramerateChangeCallbackBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitShowCameraPreviewAtBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityCameraCaptureExtentsBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnitySendWWWConnectionBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceUniqueIdentifierBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityAdvertisingTrackingEnabledBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitStopBroadcastingBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityDisplayManager_DisplaySystemResolutionBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceNameBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetLocationServiceStartUpdatingLocationBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityDisplayManager_PrimaryDisplayIndexBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceCPUCountBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS102orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceSupportedOrientationsBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceIsStylusTouchSupportedBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetJoystickCountBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityPrepareScreenshotBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnitySystemLanguageBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityEnumVideoCaptureDevicesBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetMainScreenContextGLESBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityStartFrameRenderingBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnitySystemNameBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_SetSelectionBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityDisplayManager_DisplayRenderingBuffersBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDestroyUnityRenderSurfacesBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityPresentContextCallbackBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDisplayManager_DisplayCountBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetLocationServiceIsServiceEnabledByUserBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceCanShowWideColorBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityDisplayManager_DisplayRenderingResolutionBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityDisplayManager_SetRenderingResolutionBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityLibraryDirBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS112orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityStartWWWConnectionCustomBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityUpdateNoBackupFlagBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityOnDemandResourcesGetProgressBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityApplicationDirBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceGetDesiredAccuracyBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityAdvertisingIdentifierBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityOnDemandResourcesGetLoadingPriorityBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceDPIBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitIsMicrophoneEnabledBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetRegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranularBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityOnDemandResourcesGetResourcePathBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitCreateOverlayWindowBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitRecordingAvailableBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityCameraCaptureVerticallyMirroredBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityShouldCancelWWWBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS103orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitStartRecordingBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityBlockWWWConnectionIsDoneBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitDiscardBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDisplayManager_DisplayActiveBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitIsRecordingBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnitySetGyroUpdateIntervalBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnitySelectedRenderingAPIBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityReplayKitBroadcastingAPIAvailableBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityCoreMotionStopBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetJoystickAxisNameBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDestroyWWWConnectionBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetContextEAGLBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitPreviewBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityAddNewMetalAPIImplIfNeededBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityWWWClearCookieCacheBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitSetMicrophoneEnabledBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityiOS90orNewerBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityCachesDirBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityCameraCaptureReadToMemoryBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityCameraCaptureSetAutoFocusPointBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitGetBroadcastURLBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceGetLocationStatusBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitSetCameraEnabledBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetUnityNotifyDeferSystemGesturesChangeBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDocumentsDirBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceGetHeadingStatusBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetMetalDeviceBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceSetDistanceFilterBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceIsHeadingAvailableBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitIsCameraEnabledBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetCurrentContextEAGLBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitLastErrorBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityPauseCameraCaptureBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityCameraCaptureVideoRotationDegBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetGetLaunchImageNamesBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetLocationServiceStopUpdatingLocationBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetAppLoadCommandCountBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGfxInitedCallbackBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityPlayFullScreenVideoBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnity_il2cppNoExceptionsBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetGyroUpdateIntervalBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_GetSelectionBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityFontFallbacksBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityOnDemandResourcesCreateRequestBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceGenerationBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetLocationServiceSetHeadingUpdatesEnabledBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_StatusBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityDeviceModelBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityIsFullScreenPlayingBody", referenced
>   from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityGetGLViewBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityKeyboard_SetInputHiddenBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o
>   "_SetLocationServiceIsHeadingUpdatesEnabledBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityOnDemandResourcesReleaseBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitIsBroadcastingBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitAPIAvailableBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnitySystemVersionBody", referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o   "_SetUnityReplayKitStopRecordingBody",
>   referenced from:
>         _SetAllUnityFunctionsForDynamicPlayerLib in DynamicLibEngineAPI.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried upgrading to the latest unity version, but the problem stays the same.

Removing the reference to DynamicLibEngineAPI-functions.h and DynamicLibEngineAPI.mm from the Classes folder of the Unity build solves the problem for me.